# Adding attribute options programmatically are not available for use immediatly

Tags: attributes, cache, custom-options

I'm creating Magento attribute options via a script, but I need to then be able to get the new ID and use it straight away in the same script.

At the moment it's not pulling the id through - if I kill the script and re-start it it picks up the created option and returns the ID, but not as part of the same script.

Here is the code I am using:

```
       $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute($key);
       if ($attr->usesSource()) {
               $vattr_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($value);
       }else{
               echo "No Source";
               $vattr_id = false;
       }


    if($vattr_id){
            return $vattr_id;
    }else{

            $attr_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');
            $attr = $attr_model->loadByCode('catalog_product', $key);
            $attr_id = $attr->getAttributeId();

            $option['attribute_id'] = $attr_id;
            $option['value'][$value][0] = $value;
            $option['value'][$value][1] = $value;

            $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
            $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
            $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute($key);
            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                   $vattr_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($value);
                    echo "AttrID: $vattr_id";
            }

    }
```

Running this (with the required Mage::app() etc), creates the option, you can see it in the Magento backend, but the $vattr_id is NULL. If I reload the script, then it finds the attribute option in that first block as it should.

I guess it's something to do with how Magento is caching the models, but not sure where I need to look to clear these?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you aren't doing this with an install script?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, 

It's part of a data importer, we pull in XML feeds, populate the data etc, and part of that is checking for new attribute options that don't already exist and creating them - we don't know what they are until the import runs, sometimes there are many, sometimes none, so it's just a standardlone importer.

Comment: You seem to have a good answer provided to you. Does it work for you? If so, can you accept it? If not, can you clarify what isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using slightly different approach to save attribute option value

```
$arg_value = 'your option label';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'your attribute code');
        $flag=0;

    foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option )
    {

        if($arg_value == $option['label'])
        {

            unset($attribute);
            $flag=1;
            return $option['value'] ; 
        }
    }
    if($flag==0){
        $attribute_model        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
        $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table') ;

        $attribute_code         = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
        $attribute              = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

        $attribute_table        = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
        $options                = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);

        $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value);
        $result = array('value' => $value);
        $attribute->setData('option',$result);
        $attribute->save();

        $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
        foreach ( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option )
        {
            if($arg_value == $option['label'])
            {
                unset($attribute);
                return $option['value'] ; 
            }
        }

    }
```

this will create new option value if it not exist and return id of option.

Comment: Just building this functionality into an import routine and came across this code, what does `$arg_attribute` refer to?

Comment: @b3njamin $arg_attribute is refer to your attribute_code

Comment: using flag here is unnecessary because if option found it will be returned

Answer (score 2):

I have a potentially slightly cleaner solution:

```
<?php # sql/module_setup/upgrade-0.4.0-0.5.0.php

$options = array('First new option',
                 'Second new option',
                 'nth new option');


$option = array('attribute_id' => 
    Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode(
         Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 
         'attribute_code_here'
    )
 );

for ($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {
    $option['values'][1000+$i] = $options[$i];
}

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($option);

$installer->endSetup();
```

You could even go as far as removing the for loop and manually coding the array but I prefer this, myself. Adjust the options, adjust the attribute code (find `attribute_code_here`) and you're set. Old options are left in place. The `1000+$i` is used to determine the sort order, adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to get the id of an just created attribute option, to set it in a product. In my custom class i use this method to add an new option to an select attribute:

```
public function addAttributeOption($optionName)
{
    $newOptions = array();
    $newOptions['attribute_id'] = $this->myAttributeId;
    $newOptions['value']['dummy-array-name'][0] = $optionName;

    $setup = new \Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $setup->addAttributeOption($newOptions);
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

But i must destroy my class object with unset() before i can get the ids like with a method like this:

```
public function getAttributeOptionNameId($optionName)
{
    $sourceModel = \Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($this->myAttributeName)
        ->getSource();
    $valuesIds = array_map(array($sourceModel, 'getOptionId'), array($optionName));
    return $valuesIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all kinds of other solutions (clearing the caches, destroying the source and attribute objects etc.), but the only one that worked was re-creating the source object using the same code that is used in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract::getSource()`:

```
$source = Mage::getModel($authorAttr->getSourceModel());
if (!$source) {
    throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav',
        Mage::helper('eav')->__('Source model "%s" not found for attribute "%s"',$this->getSourceModel(), $this->getAttributeCode())
    );
}
$authorSrc = $source->setAttribute($authorAttr);
```

The option set is in the object attributes, so after the source object has been recreated the options are reloaded and the new attribute can be found.